# dictionary searching with datetime key for specific day, not all datetime key

Tags: datetime, python-3.x, dictionary

I have date in the following format:

{datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 27, 0, 28, 0, 878356): {data},datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 27, 0, 28, 0, 878365): {data}, datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 28, 0, 28, 0, xxxxxx): {data}}

Basically, data can be measured at multiple points during given date. 
I would like to return all measurements for a given date - for example, here May 27. I don't care about specific time of the day, just date.
How do I do this? In this case I would like to return first two records and not have third one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import datetime
myobj = {datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 27, 0, 28, 0, 878356): 123.12313,datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 27, 0, 28, 0, 878365): 14.23432, datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 28, 0, 28, 0, 131234): 8.1233}
for date in myobj:
    if date.strftime('%y%m%d') == '140527':
        print(myobj[date])
```

Which runs as:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> myobj = {datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 27, 0, 28, 0, 878356): 123.12313,datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 27, 0, 28, 0, 878365): 14.23432, datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 28, 0, 28, 0, 131234): 8.1233}
>>> for date in myobj:
...     if date.strftime('%y%m%d') == '140527':
...         print(myobj[date])
... 
123.12313
14.23432
>>>
```

This uses [`date.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to get the year, month, and date as a string. In this case, we want it to return `'140527'`. If it does, print the data.